# Swift: Unable to interact with Slide out menu

Tags: swift

I am attempting to build a slide out menu for my iOS app and adapted from this Ray Wandelich [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/299-how-to-create-your-own-slide-out-navigation-panel-in-swift). As I setup my views programmatically and do not require `panGestures`, I adapted parts of the tutorial.

However, my adaptation somehow doesn't allow me to interact with the `sideMenu`, ie my `sideMenu` `tableView` is totally frozen. The `mainView` works just fine. My implementation:

```
//At viewDidLoad of my ContainerViewController, I call setupViewControllers
fileprivate func setupViewControllers() {
    let mainView = mainController.view!
    let sideMenuView = sideMenuController.view!
    mainView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sideMenuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    view.addSubview(mainView)
    view.addSubview(sideMenuView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mainView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        mainView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        mainView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        mainView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

        sideMenuView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        sideMenuView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: menuWidth),
        sideMenuView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        sideMenuView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        ])

    addChild(mainController)
    addChild(sideMenuController)
    mainController.didMove(toParent: self)
    sideMenuController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

I tried doing `view.insertSubViews(view: sideMenuView, at: 0)` but my `sideMenuView` is still frozen.

Comment: When you run the app do you get see the side menu view on the screen as well ?

Comment: @SharkesMonken the sideMenu is hidden when the app runs until I tap a button to reveal it. When it's revealed, the tableView is frozen.

Comment: Did you enable userInteraction property ? I mean by default you should be able to interact with it but just to confirm check that out.

Comment: @SharkesMonken I did not, but I just tried `tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` at my `sideMenuController` and it still didn't work.